# Java while loop nested in a for loop.

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I have this simple code sample that I don't understand.

```
// Compute integer powers of 2.

class Power {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        int e, result;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            result = 1;
            e = i;
            while (e > 0) {
                result *= 2;
                e--;
            }
            System.out.println("2 to the " + i + " power is " + result);
        }
    }
}
```

Producing this output.

```
2 to the 0 power is 1
2 to the 1 power is 2
2 to the 2 power is 4
2 to the 3 power is 8
2 to the 4 power is 16
2 to the 5 power is 32
2 to the 6 power is 64
2 to the 7 power is 128
2 to the 8 power is 256
2 to the 9 power is 512
```

Questions:

1. How come `result` is not always 2, since it's being re-initialized every time the `for` loop is entered?
2. The `e--` decrement doesn't do a thing either, does it? Since, again, `e` is being set equal to `i` afresh on every iteration.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried sitting down with pencil and paper and executing the code yourself?

Comment: e and result are not being reinitialized.  You seem to have a misunderstanding about scope and how for loops work.  But, e and result are both initialized outside the loop body.  Then they are changed within the loop.  Try and step through it with pencil and paper to get a better understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How come result is not always 2, since it's being re-initialized every
>   time the for loop is entered?

Yes, it is being re-initialized but only in the first loop. Your inner loop is looping `while(e > 0)` and double result at each iteration. Then once you are done looping, you pring the result and restart. The value of `result` will depend on `e` which define the number of times `result` is doubled.

> The e-- decrement doesn't do a thing either, does it? Since, again, e
>   is being set equal to i afresh on every iteration.

Again, yes it is being set back to i at each iteration but that doesn't mean it is useless. At each iteration, e is set back to the new value of i, and then you use it to create an inner loop `while e > 0` where at each iteration you decrement e of 1 and double the result.

Comment: Oh, I get it!!! 

So the result IS always (2), except that when your 'e' is say 4, it's (1x2)(1x2)(1x2)(1x2) to give 2^4, at each iteration decrementing "e" so that when while evals to false (e == 0) it breaks out of the while and returns to the top of the for. 

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The two questions kind of go together.

You see, e is set to i which is actually INCREASED each iteration.
And the higher e is, the more often the inner while will be worked through.

So for example in your 3rd for iteration

```
i = 2
e = 2
result = 1
```

So first while:

```
result = result*2 = 1*2 = 2
e = 1
```

e is still > 0 so after the second while:

```
result = result*2 = 2*2 = 4
e = 0
```

And there we go.

e-- did something twice and result is NOT 2.

Answer (score 0):

`result` and `e` are re-initialized at the top of the `for` loop, but are modified within the `while` loop before `result` is displayed at the bottom of the `for` loop.